# .NET Framework Method Not Found 'Void System.GC.Collect'

Tags: frameworks, internals, dcom

I'm trying to run some service and I'm getting this message

> Method not found: 'Void System.GC.Collect(Int32,
>   System.GCCollectionMode)'

I suspect the server because this service runs on other servers.
I really want to know what the source of this problem because I came across this problem on other servers.
I try to take of code from my service and finally I realized that even I run a console application with only one static main and call the GC I get this error,
I'm using Windows Server 2003 with Framework 2.0 and 3.5

Comment: Is your .NET framework set in your system path environment variable?  Typically, the .NET framework is located on a path like C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.

Comment: It's was not set in the path variable, but I set it and still no change...

Comment: I'm not sure is this helps but I think the function is supported in .net 3.5 SP1. Do you have service pack installed? .NET Framework
Supported in: 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP1, 2.0 SP1

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with your .NET framework installation.  What if you attempt to repair it using http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30135?

Comment: still not working .... I would like to mention that if I compile this project at Frame work 4 it's work, at framework 2 it's doesn't ... when i call to the GC.Collect() it's working only when i call to 'Void System.GC.Collect(Int32, System.GCCollectionMode)' it's doesn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your console application make sure your target framework is not set to Client Profile FrameWork 3.5.

The above setting is in Application tab of your project properties

If you want to use GCCollectionMode and Framework 2.0 you will have to install .NET 2.0 Service Pack 1